# How to execute DataTable.Select() for a column of custom class type for a particular element in that C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I'm using a class which holds a color value and a index value and by which I'm forming a column

```
Class ColorWithIndex 
{ 
   System.Drawing.Color Color; 
   Int Index;

   public ColorWithIndex(System.Drawing.Color color, Int index)
   {
       Color = color;
       Index = index;
   }
} 

DataTable dataTable = New DataTable(); 

dataTable.Columns.Add("ColorColumn", typeOf(ColorWithIndex));

dataTable.Rows.Add(new ColorWithIndex(Color.Red, 1));
dataTable.Rows.Add(new ColorWithIndex(Color.Green, 2));
dataTable.Rows.Add(new ColorWithIndex(Color.Blue, 3));
```

So Can I have the query like.

```
ColorWithIndex greenOne = new ColorWithIndex(Color.Green, 2);

DataRow[] _queried = dataTable.Select("ColorColumn = " + greenOne);
```

Comment: Make Color and Index public so you can get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataTable.Select(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_) method cannot search for arbitrary types.

Implement the `ToString` method in `ColorWithIndex` class. For example:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Color.Name + " " + Index;
}
```

Then use the Convert function when searching:

```
dataTable.Select("CONVERT(ColorColumn, System.String) = '" + greenOne + "'")
```

Comment: Amazing answer thank you very much it solved my Issue

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
DataRow[] _queried = dataTable.Select(t => t.Color == greenOne.Color && t.Index == greenOne.Index);
```